# Issue in showing series of data in javascript

Tags: javascript

My friends,

i have made a tooltip here: http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/83/ and I have defined two "functions" for tooltip like:

```
function mousemove1(d) {
    div
      .text("data 1: " + d.value + " at " + formatTime(new Date(d.time)))
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
}

function mousemove2(d) {
    div
      .text("data2: " + d.value + " at " + formatTime(new Date(d.time)))
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
}
```

but when i move the cursor it shows the value of "data2" where is data1? I want the tooltip recognize the two series of data and show their value when we hover around the two curves of graph.

Comment: 1. Both handlers overwrite div's text (so whenever the second one is called - the first one gets overwritten) 2. Adding the value (instead of overwriting) might also not be a good approach, since you cannot rely on the order of event handlers execution.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You're populating the `div` with new data in each function. `data2` overwrites `data1`.
See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/QBDGB/86/) for taking care of that issue. Mind the `json` variable I added at line `123`.

**2.** Another thing - you're `.svg`s overlap. It's showing only `svg2` data since it doesn't read you're going over `svg1`.

To confirm this - when you go over a green, or dark green spot - you have only `data2`, but when you take the mouse over a blue spot you see both `data1` and `data2` (in the link I posted above).

After you go over one blue spot, if you go over a green spot, the `svg1` data stays static. Until you go over another blue spot.

Comment: Thank you for replying :) So I should define two div (div1 and div2) ? but it does not show anything http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/84/

Comment: Thank you so much for your time indeed :) in order to make sure what you said I added a check box to see the layer separetly http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/89/ but I still do not know how to fix, should I add two svgs?

Comment: @sasha, I think you should make one `mousemove` function. Triggering the event only for moving over the `svg` isn't really what you want. Make one `mousemove` for the whole grid, send it all the data (`svg1` & `svg2`) and build the tooltip from that. See http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/QBDGB/96/ It's not perfect, but better regarding the issue in discussion.

Comment: yes you are right! Thanks indeed for your help :) but please take a look at what tooltip show. When I mouse hover I can not understand the value of where it is showing.. it does not match with x axis and y axis. I did another try to show the tooltip with circles, it shows the values correctly but the circles does not move on the curve http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/52/ but I do not know why they show correct value but the graph that we made cannot..

Comment: I see a problem in the accuracy, I'm not sure if the problem is in the graphical representation on the grid, or in the data received for the div/circles. I don't know enough about `svg` to answer that... But this is a seperate issue, it exists in the original fiddle as well (the one linked in the question). We solved the problem with the div :)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding two handler on the mousemove event, so the last one overwrites the previous one.

I think you should pass both the parameters at the same time to any of the handlers.

Here is how you can do it,

```
function mousemove1(d1, d2) {
div
  .text("data 1: " + d1.value + " at " + formatTime(new Date(d1.time)) +"  "+ "data 2: " + d2.value + " at " + formatTime(new Date(d2.time)))
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
}
```

Also if you have to pass only one datalist available at a time then you can do something like this:

```
function mousemove(d, caseNum) {
    switch(caseNum) {
    case1: // do your work of first case
        break;
    case2:  // do your work of second case
       break;
    case3:  // do your work of third case
       break;
    }
}
```

In the second method, you have to pass the `caseNum` parameter to tell the case number.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) it was great, but you think there is no way to make them separate so when the cursor moves it can recognize it belongs to which set and show the relevant data?

Comment: @sasha: Do you want to show both the data at the same time or only one based on some condition? If both at the same time, then the above one is the better way (IMO), since it reduces code redundancy.

Comment: @sasha: See my updated answer if you want to pass only one datalist at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and attention :) but it still shows the data of onse series and that is strange http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/92/

Comment: The data you are passing is an array, so `d.value` is undefined. You have to use `d[0].value`. Also in your code you have used `caseNum == 1` two time. It should be `caseNum==1` and `caseNum==2`.

Comment: @sasha: The problem is that the second path is overlapping with the first path (second one on covering the first one). So where ever you take mouse the mousemove event is triggred on the second path not the first one. http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/94/